# Lookup the MIN value in a SQL recursive query at the parent level?

Tags: sql, recursion

I have a standard recursive lookup script that uses a CTE, a "union all", parent-child relationship. The problem I am trying to solve is that I would like to capture two attributes from the lowest level child record and place it on the highest level parent record.

The attributes are:

1. The maximum depth of the parent's child levels. In my data, not all parents have the same levels of depth in the child records. Some only span 1 level below the parent and some span as far as 10 levels below. On the output of my query, I would like to see the parent record contain the maximum number of levels of depth in their children.
2. All records in my data contain a field value, but this value is only important on the lowest level of the hierarchy. I would like the query to output the value of the lowest level child on the parent record.

Table:

```
childid, name, keyfield, parentid, level
11, Sally, xyz123, null, 1
1, Alex, xyz456, 11, 2
7, John, abc123, null, 1
3, Erin, abc456, 7, 2
4, Jen, abc789, 3, 3
```

Desired output:

```
childid, name, keyfield_max, keyfield_min
11, Sally, xyz123, xyz456
7, John, abc123, abc789
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Edit your question and show the query that you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Version:

```
DECLARE @data TABLE(childid int, [name] nvarchar(128), keyfield varchar(30), parentid int, [level] int);
INSERT @data VALUES(11, 'Sally', 'xyz123', null, 1), (1, 'Alex', 'xyz456', 11, 2), (7, 'John', 'abc123', null, 1), (3, 'Erin', 'abc456', 7, 2), (4, 'Jen', 'abc789', 3, 3);

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT d.*, d.childid AS topid FROM @data d WHERE d.parentid IS NULL
        UNION ALL
    SELECT d.*, cte.topid FROM cte INNER JOIN @data d ON cte.childid = d.parentid
)

SELECT
    d.childid, d.[name], t.keyfield_max, t.keyfield_min
FROM @data d
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT MAX(cte.keyfield) AS keyfield_max, MIN(cte.keyfield) AS keyfield_min FROM cte WHERE cte.topid = d.childid) t
WHERE d.parentid IS NULL
```